# How transform a list into a corpus in r?

Tags: r, list, corpus

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920330/split-a-huge-dataframe-in-many-smaller-dataframes-to-create-a-corpus-in-r/) I asked how to split a huge dataframe to create a corpus. Thanks to the answer I was able to create a list from a dataframe. 
My problem was still **obtaining a corpus from the list I created** in order to do some text mining and cluster the data according to the search term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem I just applied the as.VCorpus function of the tm package to the list I created before:

```
new_corpus <- as.VCorpus(new_list)
```

Check if the new object is a corpus:

```
class(new_corpus)
[1] "VCorpus" "Corpus"
```

I thus created a "volatile corpus". As written in the R documentation:

> A volatile corpus is fully kept in memory and thus all changes only affect the corresponding R object.