# Create a "virtual" corpus in python

Tags: python, r, dataframe, virtualization, corpus

I need to create a corpus from a huge dataframe (or any python equivalent to the r dataframe) by splitting it in so many dataframes as the usernames.

For example I start from a dataframe like this:

```
username    search_term
name_1      "some_text_1"
name_1      "some_text_2"
name_2      "some_text_3"
name_2      "some_text_4"
name_3      "some_text_5"
name_3      "some_text_6"
name_3      "some_text_1"

[...]

name_n      "some_text_n-1"
```

And I want to obtain:

```
data frame 1
username    search_term
name_1      "some_text_1"
name_1      "some_text_2"

data frame 2
username    search_term
name_2      "some_text_3"
name_2      "some_text_4"
```

And so on..

I already asked this question for R, but now I realised that using the python NLTK could be an advantage for me. 
I found out that in R i can create a virtual corpus. Is it the same in python? Or is there another way to solve this problem in python?

To see how I solved this problem in R see:

[Split a huge dataframe in many smaller dataframes to create a corpus in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920330/split-a-huge-dataframe-in-many-smaller-dataframes-to-create-a-corpus-in-r)

[How transform a list into a corpus in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061912/how-transform-a-list-into-a-corpus-in-r/34061913#34061913)

Answer (score -1):

here is your solution in R

I created a similar data.frame `df`

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:6, each = 2) , value = 1:12)
```

Here are indexes of groups and names for future small data.frames

```
idx <- unique(df$group)
nms <- paste0('df', idx)
```

Next, in a `for` loop I create these small data.frames

```
for(i in idx){
  df_tmp <- df[df$group == i, ]
  do.call('<-', list(nms[i], df_tmp))
}
```

Comment: The question wasn't how to do it in R.  They linked to questions that ask for how to do it in R and the answer there is to use `split` which is a much better approach.